# Limit instance count with Autofac?

Tags: inversion-of-control, autofac, multiple-instances

I have a console app that will create an instance of a class and execute a method on it, and that's really all it does (but this method may do a lot of things). The class is determined at runtime based on command line args, and this is registered to Autofac so it can be correctly resolved, supplying class-specific constructor parameters extracted from the command line. All this works.

Now, I need to impose a system-wide limit to the number of instances per class that can be running at any one time. I will probably use a simple SQL database to keep track of number of allowed and running instances per class, and I have no problem with the SQL side of things.

But how do I actually impose this limit in a nice manner using Autofac?

I am thinking that I would have some "slot service" that would do something like this:

1. Try to reserve a new instance "slot".
2. If no more slots, log a message and terminate the process.
3. If slot successfully reserved, create instance and return it.

My idea is also to free the instance's slot in the class' Dispose method, preferably by using another method on the slot service.

How would I fit this into Autofac?

One possibility would be to register the class I want to instantiate with a lambda/delegate that does the above steps. But in that case, how do I "terminate"? Throw an exception? That would require some code to catch the exception and either log it or simply ignore it before terminating the process. I don't like it. I'd like the entire slot reservation stuff inside the delegate, lambda or service.

Another solution might be to do the slot reservation outside of Autofac, but that also seems somewhat messy.

I would prefer a solution where the "slot service" itself can be nicely unit tested, i.e. non-static and with an interface, and preferably resolved with Autofac.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here... Any suggestions?

This is my "best bet" so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ReadCommandLine(args, out Type itemClass, out Type paramsClass, out Type paramsInterface, out object parameters);
    BuildContainer(itemClass, paramsClass, paramsInterface, parameters);
    IInstanceHandler ih = Container.Resolve<IInstanceHandler>();
    if (ih.RegisterInstance(itemClass, out long instanceid))
    {
        try
        {
            Container.Resolve<IItem>().Execute();
        }
        finally
        {
            ih.UnregisterInstance(itemClass, instanceid);
        }
    }
}
```